# laravel foreach loop through an array in blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I have an array which I would like to output in the edit template in a foreach loop.
But I get an error cannot access offset of type string on string

In blade I have this:

```html
@foreach ($post->cage as $c  )

    <div data-repeater-item="">
    
      <div class="form-group">
    
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Make</label>

        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Comment</label>
        
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" name="cage[1][comment]" value="{{ $c['comment'] }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>

@endforeach
```

The controller is very basic

```
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 */
public function edit(string $id): Response
{
    
    return response()->view('post.edit', [
        'post' => Posts::findOrFail($id),
    ]);
}
```

a vardump gives this

```
array(3) {   
    ["level"]=> string(6) "middle"
    ["comment"]=> string(4) "joe2"
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["level"]=> string(6) "middle"
        ["comment"]=> string(4) "joe2" }
}
```

Any idea how to make the foreach to get the value?
Do I have to add something in the controller? decode or something?
Thanks in advance

Extra edit.
Cage is a text field which can store an array

```php
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 */
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {

$table->text('zone')->nullable();
    $table->text('cage')->nullable(); 
    });
}
```

In the model file

```php
protected $casts = [
    'cage' => 'array'
];
```

edit2: Change the textfield into a jsonfield. The foreach loop through an array works now fine. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: How is the `cage` relationship/accessor defined?

Comment: What did you `var_dump`? What is `->cage`?

Comment: What if you add `is_array()`  inside your `foreeach`? Because it's not an Array. Its a string

Comment: @brombeer and Vivick I updated the post with an edit, to explain the cage field. Vardump i did this   
            var_dump($post->cage);

Comment: Maybe the array cast on the text field doesnt work. try working with json_encode and json_decode as long as your column is a text field. also, for the sake of understanding, trying adding a `if (!is_array($c)) dump($c)` within the foreach loop (caution: dump sometimes only works within @php)

Comment: @Alex I did a json_decode   foreach (json_decode($post->cage) as $c)  but htis gives the json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given  error and when  using encode it give me the foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given      a dump gives this "middle"  and "joe2"

Comment: @Missblues obviously your values are sometimes arrays and sometimes string. add before mentioned is_array or is_string checks and go on from there

Comment: share Posts Model may be you need to add cage in $with

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input. The text field and the array issue made me think. I changed the field type. Instead of a textfield I changed it into a json field. The foreach loop works now fine.

Comment: @missblues Please post your solution as regular answer and mark it accepted once SO allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution would be to change your column type to `json` instead of `text`: Update your `posts.cage` migration from:

```php
$table->text('cage')->nullable();
```

to:

```php
$table->json('cage')->nullable();
```

Or to this (if you want to always have an empty array as default):

```php
$table->json('cage')->nullable()->default('[]');
```

---

Additionally, may i also suggest adding a key to your form:

```php
@foreach ($post->cage as $cageKey => $cage)
    <div data-repeater-item="{{$cageKey}}">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Make</label>
        <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Comment</label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" name="cage[{{$cageKey}}][comment]" value="{{ $cage['comment'] }}" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I already figured this would be the problem. Thank you for adding the keys and updating the foreach as well.